# Explicit specialization in define causes error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope

Tags: c++, gcc, namespaces, clang, explicit-specialization

I'm getting `explicit specialization in non-namespace scope`error from this define:

```
#define DECLARE_INTERNAL_LINK_SPECIALIZATION(T, Counter) template<> struct T<Counter>
```

This is how the define is used, which triggers the error:

```
#define DECLARE_INTERNAL_LINK_BASE(T) template<int Counter> struct T
#define DECLARE_INTERNAL_LINK_SPECIALIZATION(T, Counter) template<> struct T<Counter>

namespace TestBugFix
{
    struct FPlatformTypeLayoutParameters
    {
        DECLARE_INTERNAL_LINK_BASE(InternalLinkType);
        DECLARE_INTERNAL_LINK_SPECIALIZATION(InternalLinkType, __COUNTER__);
    };
}
```

I believe I'm getting this as defines do not have namespace scope. This works fine for clang, but not GCC. How may I implement the same functionality within namespace scope?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: a `#define` directive by itself cannot possibly cause any such error. It's all in how you use the defined macro.

Comment: Updated with the specific code causing the error.

Comment: Looks like this is a bug in gcc.